# new instagram api for getting a user's public content?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We are trying to use `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{provider_user_id}/media/recent/?access_token={access_token}`

to get a user's recent posts.

However, instgram says

> Public Content - all remaining capabilities to read public media on a
>   user's behalf on December 11, 2018

(https://www.instagram.com/developer)

So I guess we should be switching to new api soon.

But then, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api says

> The Instagram Graph API allows you to programmatically access
>   Instagram Business Accounts so you can more easily manage media
>   objects, view comments and metadata, and get insights and metrics with
>   custom built apps.
>
> If you are building apps for Instagram Non-Business Accounts, please
>   use the Instagram Platform API instead.

We are trying to get non-business accounts info (via oauth2 access token)
So we get to use the old api even after December 2018?

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong url to get data

you need to use this URL: users/self/media/recent to get all media uploaded by user

Your url should be like : https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token='Your_access_token'

Make sure your access_token have that permission to get this data.

I have used [This Repository](https://github.com/vinkla/instagram) to get media.